# Import rasterio failed. Reason: image not found

Tags: python, import, conda, rasterio, conda-forge

I'm going to use rasterio in python. I downloaded rasterio via

```
conda install -c conda-forge rasterio
```

But I cannot import it due to the following import error. I've read some related questions and I'm not sure if that's because the mixture of default and conda-forge channels. I'm completely new to this, and I'm wondering what's the next step for me. Thank you!

```
>>>import rasterio
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-350e27267e59>", line 1, in <module>
    import rasterio

  File "/Users/miaoxinran/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasterio/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from rasterio._base import (

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/miaoxinran/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasterio/_base.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgif.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/miaoxinran/anaconda3/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I add my conda info below in case it may help.

```
 conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/miaoxinran/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/miaoxinran/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/miaoxinran/.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.5
    conda-build version : 3.18.8
         python version : 3.7.1.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.15
       base environment : /Users/miaoxinran/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/miaoxinran/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/miaoxinran/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/miaoxinran/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/miaoxinran/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.5 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.1 Darwin/19.0.0 OSX/10.15
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

```
conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/miaoxinran/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2019.03                  py37_0  
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl  
absl-py                   0.8.0                    py37_0  
affine                    2.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda                  custom                   py37_1  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.3                      py_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0  
appscript                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0  
astor                     0.8.0                    py37_0  
astroid                   2.2.5                    py37_0  
astropy                   3.2.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1  
attrs                     19.1.0                   py37_1  
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
backports                 1.0                        py_2  
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.5                        py_2  
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2  
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1  
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1  
beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                    py37_1  
bitarray                  0.9.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0  
blosc                     1.16.3               hd9629dc_0  
bokeh                     1.2.0                    py37_0  
boost-cpp                 1.70.0               hd59e818_1    conda-forge
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0  
boto3                     1.15.1             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
botocore                  1.18.1             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h1d22016_1  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0  
c-ares                    1.15.0            h1de35cc_1001  
ca-certificates           2020.6.20            hecda079_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.14.12              hc4e6be7_4  
certifi                   2020.6.20        py37hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.12.3           py37hb5b8e2f_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1  
click                     7.0                      py37_0  
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               1.2.1                      py_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1  
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0  
conda                     4.8.5            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
conda-build               3.18.8                   py37_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-package-handling    1.3.11                   py37_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1  
contextlib2               0.5.5                    py37_0  
cryptography              2.5              py37hdbc3d79_1    conda-forge
curl                      7.63.0            heae2a1f_1000    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
cython                    0.29.12          py37h0a44026_0  
cytoolz                   0.10.0           py37h1de35cc_0  
dask                      2.1.0                      py_0  
dask-core                 2.1.0                      py_0  
dbus                      1.13.6               h90a0687_0  
deap                      1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 4.4.0                    py37_1  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
distributed               2.1.0                      py_0  
docutils                  0.14                     py37_0  
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0  
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0  
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
ffmpeg                    4.0                  h01ea3c9_0  
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h5d5b041_1  
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0  
freexl                    1.0.5             h0b31af3_1002    conda-forge
fribidi                   1.0.5                h1de35cc_0  
future                    0.17.1                   py37_0  
gast                      0.3.2                      py_0  
geos                      3.6.2             h0a44026_1004    conda-forge
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3  
gevent                    1.4.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
giflib                    5.1.7                h01d97ff_1    conda-forge
glib                      2.56.2               hd9629dc_0  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h6ef4df4_2  
graphite2                 1.3.13               h2098e52_0  
graphviz                  2.40.1               hefbbd9a_2  
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h1de35cc_0  
grpcio                    1.16.0          py37h9011c5e_1000    conda-forge
h5py                      2.8.0            py37h878fce3_3  
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hb8d4a28_0  
hdf4                      4.2.13                        0    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.2               hfa1e0ec_1  
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py37_2  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0  
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1  
idna                      2.8                      py37_0  
imageio                   2.5.0                    py37_0  
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0  
importlib_metadata        0.17                     py37_1  
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233  
ipykernel                 5.1.1            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.6.1            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.0                      py_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jasper                    2.0.14               h636a363_1  
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0  
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0  
jedi                      0.13.3                   py37_0  
jinja2                    2.10.1                   py37_0  
jmespath                  0.10.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
joblib                    0.13.2                   py37_0  
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
json-c                    0.13.1            h575e443_1002    conda-forge
json5                     0.8.4                      py_0  
jsonschema                3.0.1                    py37_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.3.1                      py_0  
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0  
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0  
jupyterlab                1.0.2            py37hf63ae98_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.0.0                      py_0  
kealib                    1.4.7                h40e48e4_6  
keras                     2.2.4                         0  
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0  
keras-base                2.2.4                    py37_0  
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1  
keyring                   18.0.0                   py37_0  
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37h0a44026_0  
krb5                      1.16.2            h24a3359_1000    conda-forge
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5  
libcurl                   7.63.0            h76de61e_1000    conda-forge
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libdap4                   3.19.1            hae55d67_1000    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libgdal                   2.2.4                h7b1ea53_2  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7  
libkml                    1.3.0             hed7d534_1010    conda-forge
liblief                   0.9.0                h2a1bed3_2  
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                h5e45101_3    conda-forge
libopencv                 3.4.2                h7c891bd_1  
libopus                   1.3                  h1de35cc_0  
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0  
libpq                     10.6              hbe1e24e_1000    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.9.2                hd9629dc_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0  
libspatialite             4.3.0a              ha12ebda_19  
libssh2                   1.8.0             hf30b1f0_1003    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.10               hcb84e12_2  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h6bb4b03_2  
libvpx                    1.7.0                h378b8a2_0  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hf6e021a_1  
libxslt                   1.1.33               h33a18ac_0  
lightfm                   1.15                     pypi_0    pypi
llvm-openmp               4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
llvmlite                  0.29.0           py37h98b8051_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1  
lxml                      4.3.4            py37hef8c89e_0  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2  
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
matplotlib                3.1.0            py37h54f8f79_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0  
mkl                       2019.4                      233  
mkl-service               2.0.2            py37h1de35cc_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.12           py37h5e564d8_0  
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37h27c97d8_0  
mlxtend                   0.17.0                     py_0    conda-forge
mock                      3.0.5                    py37_0  
more-itertools            7.0.0                    py37_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                h3018a27_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0  
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37h04f5b5a_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0  
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0  
nbconvert                 5.5.0                      py_0  
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1  
networkx                  2.3                        py_0  
ninja                     1.9.0            py37h04f5b5a_0  
nltk                      3.4.4                    py37_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2  
notebook                  6.0.0                    py37_0  
numba                     0.44.1           py37h6440ff4_0  
numexpr                   2.6.9            py37h7413580_0  
numpy                     1.16.4           py37hacdab7b_0  
numpy-base                1.16.4           py37h6575580_0  
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
opencv                    3.4.2            py37h6fd60c2_1  
openjpeg                  2.3.1                hdc36067_1    conda-forge
openpyxl                  2.6.2                      py_0  
openssl                   1.0.2u               h0b31af3_0    conda-forge
packaging                 19.0                     py37_0  
pandas                    0.24.2           py37h0a44026_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
pango                     1.42.4               h060686c_0  
parso                     0.5.0                      py_0  
partd                     1.0.0                      py_0  
path.py                   12.0.1                     py_0  
pathlib2                  2.3.4                    py37_0  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pcre                      8.43                 h0a44026_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0  
pexpect                   4.7.0                    py37_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pillow                    6.1.0            py37hb68e598_0  
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0  
pixman                    0.38.0               h1de35cc_0  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0  
pluggy                    0.12.0                     py_0  
ply                       3.11                     py37_0  
poppler                   0.65.0               ha097c24_1  
poppler-data              0.4.9                         1    conda-forge
proj4                     5.0.1                h1de35cc_0  
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                    py37_0  
protobuf                  3.9.2            py37h0a44026_0  
psutil                    5.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0  
py                        1.8.0                    py37_0  
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37h1413db1_2  
py-opencv                 3.4.2            py37h7c891bd_1  
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h1de35cc_9  
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py37hdbc3d79_0  
pydotplus                 2.0.2                    py37_1  
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0  
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0  
pylint                    2.3.1                    py37_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.26           py37h0a44026_0  
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.0                      py_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2  
pyrsistent                0.14.11          py37h1de35cc_0  
pysocks                   1.7.0                    py37_0  
pytables                  3.4.4            py37h13cba08_0  
pytest                    5.0.1                    py37_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.3.0                    py37_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.3.2                    py37_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.1             h145921a_1000    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_11  
python.app                2                        py37_9  
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.3.0                   py3.7_0    pytorch
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0  
pywavelets                1.0.3            py37h1d22016_1  
pyyaml                    5.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
pyzmq                     18.0.0           py37h0a44026_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1  
qtawesome                 0.5.7                    py37_1  
qtconsole                 4.5.1                      py_0  
qtpy                      1.8.0                      py_0  
rasterio                  0.36.0           py37h0dff353_2  
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0  
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37h1de35cc_0  
s3transfer                0.3.3            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
scikit-image              0.15.0           py37h0a44026_0  
scikit-learn              0.23.1                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0  
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0  
snappy                    1.1.7                he62c110_3  
snowballstemmer           1.9.0                      py_0  
snuggs                    1.4.7                      py_0    conda-forge
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0  
soupsieve                 1.8                      py37_0  
sphinx                    2.1.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.2                      py_0  
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_0  
spyder-kernels            0.5.1                    py37_0  
sqlalchemy                1.3.5            py37h1de35cc_0  
sqlite                    3.29.0               ha441bb4_0  
statsmodels               0.10.0           py37h1d22016_0  
stopit                    1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
sympy                     1.4                      py37_0  
tbb                       2019.8               h770b8ee_0    conda-forge
tblib                     1.4.0                      py_0  
tensorboard               1.14.0           py37h80053f4_0  
tensorflow                1.14.0          mkl_py37h085be34_0  
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          mkl_py37h5a24fda_0  
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0  
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py37_1  
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0  
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0  
threadpoolctl             2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0  
torchvision               0.4.1                  py37_cpu    pytorch
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
tpot                      0.11.5                   pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.46.1                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h1de35cc_0  
update-checker            0.17                     pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0  
watermark                 2.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  0.15.4                     py_0  
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.0                    py37_0  
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37h1de35cc_0  
wurlitzer                 1.0.2                    py37_0  
xerces-c                  3.2.2             h4db8090_1003    conda-forge
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0  
xlsxwriter                1.1.8                      py_0  
xlwings                   0.15.8                   py37_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zeromq                    4.3.1                h0a44026_3  
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      0.5.1                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

I'm completely new to this. Any suggestions will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got some experience with rasterio, but I am not nearly a master with it. If I remember correctly, rasterio requires you to have installed the program GDAL(both binaries and python utilities), and some other dependencies listed on the PyPi page. I don't use conda at the moment, I like to use the regular python 3.8 installer with pip. Given what I'm seeing with your installation, I would uninstall rasterio and follow a different installation procedure.

I follow the instructions listed here: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html 
This page also has separate instructions for those using Anaconda.

The GDAL installation is by far the most annoying but once it's done, the hard part is over. The python utilities for both rasterio and gdal can be found here:
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) 
The second link is also provided on the PyPi page but I like to keep it bookmarked because there's a lot of good resources there!

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! I followed the first link and it worked!

Comment: Specifically, I uninstalled rasterio, and ran `pip install rasterio` (the "Installation from binaries" instructions for Mac OS in that link).

Comment: Great! The installation can be quite annoying and somewhat bulky, but afterwards rasterio is very nice and clean.